# Creating a multi headnode hpc cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, torque

I have a HPC cluster where several webapps are installed in docker containers, the queue is managed using Torque. Every app submits job to the HPC cluster connecting to it through ssh and then running qsub: `ssh user@cluster qsub bla blabla`. There are shared folder for exchanging data.

I am not satisfied with this setup and I'd like to know if it is possible to have a masternode running on each docker and using qsub directly inside it without doing an ssh connection. I'd prefer to use torque but I am open to other solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post your code showing your attempt so far. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Torque permits multiple submission hosts.

The names or addresses of the hosts should be added to `submit_hosts` variable in Torque server configuration here is a relevant page from the manual.

```
qmgr -c 'set server submit_hosts = headnode'
qmgr -c 'set server submit_hosts += app1'
qmgr -c 'set server submit_hosts += app2'
```

Assuming `app1` and `app2` are domain names of the docker containers. You will need to configure name resolution.

For more details and other options see [Torque manual](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/1-installConfig/serverConfig.htm#configJobSubHost).